# Cascading function definition tooltips

Tags: jsdoc

I have a function that has a configuration object as a param, which has a function as one of its properties. I have defined the types with JSDoc with something like this:

```js
/**
 * @callback ParamFunction
 * @param {any} content - description
 * @param {string} output - description
 * @returns {any} - description
 *
 * function description
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} FunctionConfig
 * 
 * ... other properties
 * 
 * @property {ParamFunction} param_function - description
 * 
 * ... other properties
 * 
 */

/**
 * 
 * @param {FunctionConfig} config - description
 * @returns {Promise<any[]>} - description
*/
export const myFunction = async ({... param_function, ...}) => {
  //do things here
}
```

And when I use the function in other files like below:

```js
import { myFunction } from 'path/to/file.js';

...

const results = await myFunction({
  ...
  param_function: () => {}   // <--- while writing this line
});
```

The VS Code tooltip only shows something like:

```
(property) param_function: ParamFunction
---
description of the function
```

whereas I would like it to show that it takes `{any} content` and `{string} output` as arguments and returns `{any}`. How would I go about changing my JSDoc to do that?